# Fluent NHibernate equivalent of Inverse on One-To-One relationship

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

It turns out that this old mapping for Customer:

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.CustomerBalances).Inverse();
```

Where CustomerBalances was an ISet.

Is wrong as there can always only be 1 entry into the CustomerBalance table.
But it is still very important that NHB do not save the CustomerBalance when we save the Customer, due to database triggers (unfortunately).

So i would like something like:

```
mapping.HasOne(x => x.CustomerBalance).Inverse();
```

It should be noted that the PK of CustomerBalance is that same as the PK of Customer.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do your 2 tables look like? How are the links currently stored?

Answer (score 2):

```
mapping.HasOne(x => x.CustomerBalance).Cascade.None();
```

Should do the trick.